# If there are no subscribers, does udp multicast put anything on the wire?

Tags: linux, unix, udp, multicast

Suppose an application is writing to a udp multicast, and all subscribers quit (or perhaps no processes ever register to read the multicast).  Does anything go out on the wire?

Answer (score 3):

The source host always sends the datagram. It is up to the router to decide whether there are group members on the other side, and if so to forward the datagram, otherwise drop it.

Comment: Will the source host send the packet out on all of its interfaces?

Comment: No, it will send it out via one NIC, according to where the IP routing tables say to send it.

Comment: If "the router" decides whether there are group members on "the other side", doesn't the host have the same information to decide on which "side" (which nic) to write the packet?  It doesn't make much sense for routing tables to specify that information for a multicast address.

Comment: Yes it does have the same information, but RFC 1112 says that only the router makes that decision. Don't ask me why. Have a look at your routing tables: you'll see multicast stuff in there.

Answer (score 1):

The packet will always be sent out.  IGMP messages, which contain information about hosts joining/leaving multicast groups, are typically only processed by routers so they know where to route multicast traffic.  So hosts generally don't have that information.

Even then, routers may not forward IGMP messages but may have static multicast routes set up to forward certain traffic anyway.  In that situation, multicast traffic could pass through routers to an intended destination even in the absence of IGMP.

Regarding which interface(s) the source host sends on, that's application defined behavior.  The sending socket sets the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` or `IPV6_MULTICAST_IF` socket option to dictate which interface multicast traffic is sent out on.  If this option is not set, the system chooses a default interface to send multicast packets out on.

Comment: Routers don't forward IGMP messages at all. They send out new ones of ther own, when the membership status at the router changes. For example, if the router gets two joins from the inside, it will only send out one join to the outside. And IGMP messages tell the router not only where but. *whether* to forward multicasts. This is the essence of how multicast works.